# how to get html dropdown selected value in ng-repeat div angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

On button click need to get the dropdown values of each row dont know where the issue is not success in retrieving,the controller goes here,

```
 $scope.values = [];
 $scope.Benifit = [{ 'BenefitType': ""},{ 'BenefitType': ""}];

 $scope.saveAllValues = function () {
       alert($scope.values);
 }
```

HTML

```
<div ng-repeat="item in Benifit">

                                    <select class="form-control-sm col-md-9" ng-modal="values[$index]">
                                        <option value="">Select</option>
                                        <option value="a">a</option>
                                        <option value="b">b</option>
                                        <option value="c">c</option>
                                        <option value="d">d</option>
                                        <option value="e">e</option>
                                    </select>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <button type="button" ng-click="saveAllValues()">Save</button>
```

Here check out the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xLdobte6/3/)

Comment: Your question is not clear. Can you create a [small demo](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for this using [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) or [snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/358993/1823841) here to show the issue happening.

Comment: @palaѕн have updated and added the fiddle will you help out

Comment: You have a typo: Its `ng-model` not `ng-modal`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a typo on your select change ng-mod**a**l with ng-mod**e**l.

```
<select class="form-control-sm col-md-9" ng-model="values[$index]">
    <option value="">Select</option>
    <option value="a">a</option>
    <option value="b">b</option>
    <option value="c">c</option>
    <option value="d">d</option>
    <option value="e">e</option>
</select>
```

[Updated Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/64wuj5yp/)